# Resize unknown number of elements to fill width of parent container

Tags: css

I need to put an unknown number of divs (likely a limit of about 5) into a parent container and always make sure they remain equally divided. I'm not sure if this can be done with CSS alone but I figured I better ask. So if we know that 3 divs are used:

```
<style>
  .menu-button { 
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
  }
</style>
<div>
   <div class="menu-button">Button X</div>
   <div class="menu-button">Button Y</div>
   <div class="menu-button">Button Z</div>
</div>
```

Seems to work, but what if the number of .menu-button divs is unknown? Is there a better way to do it so it automatically adjusts horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly I think you'll have to use tables to do this. As `<td>`'s resize itslef to fit into the full width.

HTH

Comment: +1 Agree, maybe it's not the cleanest way but one could argue that it is tabular data of one row and an unknown number of cells.

Comment: This way works quite nicely, is fast, and easy enough to style. Sorry for the delayed response and thanks.

Comment: @Anthony - Glad it is sorted. @Bazzz I agree completely, it is not the cleanest way.. but for some occasions we have to bend the rules a bit..

Answer (score 18):

To do that with any element, you have two solutions:

- make the browser simulating the table behavior
- using Flexible Box layout

For instance, to build an horizontal menu, with equal width of every `li` elements, with this HTML code :

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Element</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Element</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Element</a></li>
    ...
    <li><a href="#">N Element</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using the table layout, CSS code would look like that:

```
#menu{
  width: 100%; /* for instance */
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#menu ul{
  display: table-row;
}
#menu ul li{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Flexible Box layout is a more modern solution, and it's [pretty widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) nowadays:

```
#menu{
  width: 100%; /* for instance */
}
#menu ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#menu ul li{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this solution](http://vitaminkdesign.com/blog/2008/10/21/equidistant-objects-with-css-another-way/) ([demo page](http://www.vitaminkdesign.com/blog/files/layouts/4equidistantobjects6.htm)).

Basically, you need to make the divs `display:inline-block`, and apply `text-align:justify` to them. Then force a line break. One drawback is there will always be some space between divs, i.e. no way to make their edges touch.

Comment: this doesnt work, with `inline-block` the divs become of different width according to their content. If you specify the width you don't know what to set it to as you don't know how many divs there are. Back to start.