# Navigation bar won't add list elements without line breaking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been working on a web development project for a firm and I decided to use the FlexNav JQuery plugin  for my navigation bar: http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/ However, in the example provided they have only 5 list elements but I would like to add more. When I try to achieve this, it appears that the next elements fills into the next line: http://www.kappaskins.co/ . I have no idea what exactly is causing the issue, either the HTML or CSS? I don't believe that this shouldn't be a table issue because it seems thats either the Javascript or CSS automatically breaks the line at 5 no matter what html you input.

I think the key issue may lie in these lines:

```
 .flexnav {
   -webkit-transition: none;
   -moz-transition: none;
   -ms-transition: none;
   transition: none;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10 auto;
   width: 70%;
   max-height: 0;
 }

 .flexnav.opacity {
   opacity: 0;
 }

 .flexnav.flexnav-show {
   max-height: 2000px;
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 }

 .flexnav.one-page {
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
   right: 5%;
   max-width: 200px;
 }

 .flexnav li {
   font-size: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }
```

Here is my source code:
http://codepen.io/xjokes_henry/pen/grOwBe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple divs spread to fill width of container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921484/multiple-divs-spread-to-fill-width-of-container)

Comment: @DelightedD0D I don't quite think so, look at the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the width of the li element to 16 in the CSS here (line 182):

```
.flexnav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a6a6a2;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 16%;// 20 changed to 16 to fit one additional element
}
```

In future, try debugging tools in chrome/ff (hit f12) to edit/inspect the CSS or HTML

Comment: This is not a good way to correct this issue what happens when you want to add another menu item? The OP should use 
    `display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;` on the parent and `display: table-cell;` on the child which will scale the elements to fit without having to specify an explicit width

Comment: Yes, definitely, but given he/she uses some pre-build navigation it may require some rewriting of other CSS/HTML parts. This is definitely a quick fix only.

Comment: @BorisP  Sorry dude, but this didn't change much, perhaps you forgot an element?

Comment: It works for the example you've posted: http://i.imgur.com/nQFHXcZ.png I am of course basing this on the code you've posted here http://codepen.io/xjokes_henry/pen/grOwBe